# How do I handle closing double quotes in CSV column with python?

Tags: python, parsing, csv

This is the python script:

```
f = open('csvdata.csv','rb')
fo = open('out6.csv','wb')

for line in f:
    bits = line.split(',')
    bits[1] = '"input"'
    fo.write( ','.join(bits) )

f.close()
fo.close()
```

I have a CSV file and I'm replacing the content of the 2nd column with the string "input". However, I need to grab some information from that column content first.

The content might look like this:

```
failurelog_wl","inputfile/source/XXXXXXXX"; "**X_CORD2**"; "Invoice_2M";
"**Y_CORD42**"; "SIZE_ID37""
```

It has weird type of data as you can see, especially that it has 2 double quotes at the end of the line instead of just one that you would expect.

I need to extract the `XCORD` and `YCORD` information, like `XCORD = 2` and `YCORD = 42`, before replacing the column value. I then want to insert an extra column, named `X_Y`, which represents `(2_42)`.

How can I modify my script to do that?

Comment: You know, Python has a `csv` module you can use.

Comment: I don't know how to grab information from the 2nd column content. It has weird type of data.

Comment: The example i showed above is the 2nd column content data.

Comment: What exactly is your question? As squiguy said, you can, and perhaps should, use the csv module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). Are you trying to get the information without quotes, join it to form a new column, then store it in an entirely new csv-file?

Comment: CSV module is not helping me. Is there a way I can search for a character embedded with XCORD and YCORD and add it in new column like (2_42)?

Comment: What do you mean by embedded? If you're unsure about the position of this XCORD and YCORD, but know that they will be in a format "XCORD=2", "YCORD=2", then you could simply loop over all entries to find them. If they have a prespecified position, then perhaps splitting by `,` and indexing the resulting list will be the way to go.

Comment: I don't know why Schoolboy modified the content. The line failurelog_wl","inputfile/source/XXXXXXXX"; "**X_CORD2**"; "Invoice_2M";
"**Y_CORD42**"; "SIZE_ID37"" is the content of 2nd column only of the CSV data. The data I need is 2 and 42 attached with XCORD and YCORD words.

Comment: Edit the qeustion as it is it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use a simple regular expression to pull out the numbers you want:

```
import re

f = open('csvdata.csv','rb')
fo = open('out6.csv','wb')

for line in f:
    bits = line.split(',')

    x_y_matches = re.match('.*X_CORD(\d+).*Y_CORD(\d+).*', bits[1])
    assert x_y_matches is not None, 'Line had unexpected format: {0}'.format(bits[1])
    x_y = '({0}_{1})'.format(x_y_matches.group(1), x_y_matches.group(2))

    bits[1] = '"input"'
    bits.append(x_y)

    fo.write( ','.join(bits) )

f.close()
fo.close()
```

Note that this will only work if column 2 always says 'X_CORD' and 'Y_CORD' immediately before the numbers. If it is sometimes a slightly different format, you'll need to adjust the regular expression to allow for that. I added the assert to give a more useful error message if that happens.

You mentioned wanting the column to be named X_Y. Your script appears to assume that there is no header, and my modified version definitely makes this assumption. Again, you'd need to adjust for that if there is a header line.

And, yes, I agree with the other commenters that using the csv module would be cleaner, in general, for reading and writing csv files.

Comment: I do have a header....I wanted to have the X_Y as a new column or I can just replace the content of 2nd column instead of adding new column